# Cannot connect to teams account via navigator

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a problem when trying to connect to my teams account via my navigator (I tried chrome, firfox and Microsoft Edge).

I usually get this error after providing  login & password:
[image]

Comment: Can you share steps to repro steps or doc that you are following?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?